# 'filter()' and 'map()' can be swapped

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-stream

I have a simple stream like following:

```java
List<Long> r = l.stream()
                .filter(a->a.getB() % 2 == 0)
                .map(A::getB)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But Intellij suggests me:

> 'filter()' and 'map()' can be swapped
> Inspection info: Reports stream API call chains which can be simplified. It allows to avoid creating redundant temporary objects when traversing a collection. e.g.
>
> - collection.stream().forEach() → collection.forEach()
> - collection.stream().collect(toList/toSet/toCollection()) → new CollectionType<>(collection)

The example given by Intellij is easy to understand, but I don't understand why it suggests me to `map().filter()`.

I view the source of `ReferencePipeline` but find no clue: `map().filter()` or `filter().map()` makes no difference when comes to the temporary object related to stream implementation (`filter().map()` will have less auto-boxing if `A.b` is a primitive which makes me more confused).

So, am I missing some point of stream implementation or this is a false alarm of Intellij?

Answer (score 18):

`a.getB()` is invoked twice - once inside the filter and it is also the mapping function, so instead of doing this twice, it would be better to first map it using `getB` and then filter it out

`List<Long> r = l.stream().map(A::getB).filter(b->b % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());`

**EDIT**

If `getB` returns a `long` then `mapToLong` could be used to avoid intermediate boxing operations.

```java
List<Long> r = l.stream()
                .mapToLong(A::getB)
                .filter(b->b % 2 == 0)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

Using a static counter to count the invocation of get method:

```java
class A {
    public static int count = 0;
    private long b;

    public long getB() {
        count++;
        return b;
    }
}
```

```java
List<A> list= List.of(new A(1L), new A(3L), new A(4L));
```

```java
list.stream() 
    .filter(a -> a.getB()%2 == 0)
    .map(A::getB)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(A.count); // returns 4
```

whereas

```java
list.stream()
    .mapToLong(A::getB)
    .filter(b->b % 2 == 0)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(A.count); // returns 3
```

Comment: But what is the exact optimization here ? Let's say we have billions of elements in the list and %10 of the elements are even... Wouldn't be filtering before mapping all elements more optimized. (I mean CPU cycles)

Comment: @AliCan the catch is that you need to call the same getter in order to filter, which doesn't avoid the redundancy mentioned in the post.

Comment: @AliCan The filter function is also invoking `getB`. Assume that there are 100 elements and 10 are even. Since the `getB` is present in both `filter` and `map`, it would be invoked 100 + 10 times. But if you map and then filter, `getB` would be invoked only 100 times.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I tried to run with a static counter, for a list of 3 elements with 1 even number, the output of the counter value for the code in question was `4` and not `6`.

Comment: Thanks all, my bad. Indeed, it is obvious now.